# split text into lines by the number of characters

Tags: python, string

I have some text for example:

```
'This is a line of text over 10 characters'
```

That I need to be broken into lines consisting of no more than 10 characters without breaking words unless I need to (for example a line with work containing more than 10 characters).

The line above would turn into:

```
'This is a\nline of\ntext over\n10\ncharacters'
```

It's a fairly simple problem but I'd like to hear how people would do it. I'm going to start coding it and post my solution in a little while as well.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You need [`textwrap`](http://docs.python.org/library/textwrap.html)

```
>>> import textwrap
>>> s = 'This is a line of text over 10 characters'
>>> textwrap.fill(s, width=10)
'This is a\nline of\ntext over\n10\ncharacters'
```

Comment: I should have guessed there would be a library for it. Cheers.